# Converting TextView to hyperlinks

Tags: java, android, xml

In my android app how can i show hyperlinks as clickable links to open in browser .

For this  I am fetching json messages from backend , saving the data in SQLite database of app and then displaying them on screen using  TextView -

Fetching json messages using AsyncTask and Progress Dialog -

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

     //some code goes here

     mMessages = json.getJSONArray(TAG_MESSAGES);
                // looping through all posts according to the
                // json
                // object returned
                for (int i = 0, length = mMessages.length(); i < length; ++i) {
                JSONObject c = mMessages.getJSONObject(i);

                // gets the content of each tag and put in
                // database
                String content = c.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

                // add field in database and update
                db.addFieldInGcm(content);
    }
}
```

In onPostExecute() i am refreshing the screen with all messages saved in database using TextView lblMessage object -

```
// show messages on screen
        TextView lblMessage;
        lblMessage.setText("");
        List<String> messages = db.getAllGCMMessages();
        for (int k = messages.size() - 1; k >= 0; --k) {
            lblMessage.append(messages.get(k).toString() + "\n\n");
```

This is my XML layout for lblMessage  -

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblMessage"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="16dip"
            android:autoLink="all" ></TextView>
```

Seems like , XML **android:autoLink**  is not applicable for strings fetched from database .
So , if while displaying messages  i use something like  -

```
 if(  messages.get(k).toString().contains("http://www.") )
```

How can i change this string in clickable hyperlinks using java ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Linkify.addLinks(textView, Linkify.ALL)`.

Comment: [Here's the link to the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is my working implementation after getting answers -

```
private void showMessage() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub'
    // show messages on screen
    lblMessage.setText("");
    List<String> messages = db.getAllGCMMessages();
    for (int k = messages.size() - 1; k >= 0; --k) {

        String message  =  messages.get(k).toString();
        lblMessage.append(message + "\n\n");
     }

        Linkify.addLinks(lblMessage, Linkify.ALL);


    }
```

and to change color of hyperlinks , i editted my xml  for textview -

```
android:textColorLink="#69463d"
```

Comment: put  Linkify.addLinks(lblMessage, Linkify.ALL); outside the loop

Comment: @Nepster bro , i got yours point  :) , i editted it.